# how to get reflectance value from rgb image matlab code?

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I have a rgb image ( 500*900*3) , I try to extract for each pixel its reflectance value, I wonder if there is any function in matlab to do this ?

Comment: The RGB value of a pixel depends on the strength, color and direction of the illumination hitting that point on the object as well as the reflectance and orientation of the surface. So unless you know all those other things, you cannot derive reflectance.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: but light source is usually constant, nearly uniform and dominant, so by having some white references, it should be easy to calculate reflectance. There are some limits: specular reflection, spot (or directional) lights, self-illuminating objects. Just that reflectance should be dependent of wavelength, and with images, one have just 3 distribution (and such distribution depends on camera filters).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: yes, in a controlled environment you can measure reflectance. But this is not true in general: light color is very different in different part of scenes, because stuff is often illuminated by reflection off of other surfaces, not necessarily directly by the light source (think of white balanced settings in the sun and in the shade, and how often you have both in one photograph; and look into the effort they put in the computer graphics community to get illumination right for photo-realistic rendering).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the reflectance values separately. After you load the image on to matlab, you can use this code to extract.

lets assume your variable name is img which has the data.

```
b= img(:,:,1)
 g=img(:,:,2)
 r=img(:,:,3)
```